# How to apply style to all elements on the same level?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table and I need to change the background color of the row after I click on it (as if it was selected). The problem is that I can't change the html, and currently I can change the background color of any `.td` using `.td:focus`, but not `.tr`.

So as a workaround - can I make it so that when selecting one `.td:focus` I also apply the same style to all `.td` elements at the same level (child elements of the same parent `.tr` element)? How can I achieve this?

Comment: please share your code and attempts , so we can advise from there. (hints: tabindex / :focus-within )

Comment: @G-Cyrillus tabindex would work but as I wrote unfortunately I can't change HTML in this case. I'll check :focus-within, thanks for the hint.

Comment: exemple with focus-within : https://jsfiddle.net/s3fykwpL/ but it requires a focusable element .. within :) You might be able to add a tabindex on the fly via javascript if editing/adding HTML is not an option. is editing JS possible ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yes, JS is an option. Although I thought there might be some kind of pseudo selector that would allow me to select all the divs at the same level as the one I clicked on.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus  Thank you for the focus-within example, it looks like exactly what I need. I'm not sure why it's not working in my case. I tried hover selector and it worked: .tr:hover .td{
    background-color: green;
  }

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Can we do the other way around and after .td:focus find its .tr parent and change the background color of all its children?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus wait it worked!!! .tr:focus-within .td{
    background-color: green;
  }

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you so much! :) If you will add it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it!